# Using the inline retag option keeps appending "edited tags" for each additional edit

Tags: bug, edit-summary, inline-tag-editor

If you go to a question and use the inline retag option ("edit tags" to the right) and only change one tag, it sets "edited tags" as the edit reason. Cool.

Woops, I just noticed this other tag should be changed too, so I edit the tags again and save, but it appends a second "edited tags" message to the edit reason. Weird...

Continue on. Each additional tag edit you make within the 5-minute grace period will keep adding additional "edited tags" entries onto the end of the edit reason. It should just be a single reason.

See [a revision where I had edited tags three times in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9967165/revisions).

Comment: I'm not convinced that this needs more of a solution than "do it right the first time, or deal with a slightly aesthetically imperfect edit summary."

Comment: @Pops programmers have nasty habit of aspiring to perfection, go figure ;)